# 404 not found in root script file angular

Tags: angular

I have compiled angular project it creates dist folder running dist folder content `http://localhost/angapp/index.html` show

404 not found for these script and styles that are generated after compiling

```
runtime.9a4430f7366c332babeb.js 
main.08671498e1fe3c2f409d.js
polyfills.e11715d3ca9a8c11dd36.js ....
```

> index.html

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin="">
    <style type="text/css">@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:italic;font-weight:100;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiAyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLmE0tDMPKhSkFEkm8.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0900-097F, U+1CD0-1CF6, U+1CF8-1CF9, U+200C-200D, U+20A8, U+20B9, U+25CC, U+A830-A839, U+A8E0-A8FB;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:italic;font-weight:100;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiAyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLmE0tMMPKhSkFEkm8.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:italic;font-weight:100;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiAyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLmE0tCMPKhSkFE.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:italic;font-weight:200;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiDyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLmv1pVFteOYktMqlap.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0900-097F, U+1CD0-1CF6, U+1CF8-1CF9, U+200C-200D, U+20A8, U+20B9, U+25CC, U+A830-A839, U+A8E0-A8FB;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:italic;font-weight:200;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiDyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLmv1pVGdeOYktMqlap.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:italic;font-weight:200;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiDyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLmv1pVF9eOYktMqg.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:italic;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiDyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLm21lVFteOYktMqlap.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0900-097F, U+1CD0-1CF6, U+1CF8-1CF9, U+200C-200D, U+20A8, U+20B9, U+25CC, U+A830-A839, U+A8E0-A8FB;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:italic;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiDyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLm21lVGdeOYktMqlap.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:italic;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiDyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLm21lVF9eOYktMqg.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:italic;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiGyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLucXtAOvWDSHFF.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0900-097F, U+1CD0-1CF6, U+1CF8-1CF9, U+200C-200D, U+20A8, U+20B9, U+25CC, U+A830-A839, U+A8E0-A8FB;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:italic;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiGyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLufntAOvWDSHFF.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:italic;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiGyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLucHtAOvWDSA.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:italic;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiDyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLmg1hVFteOYktMqlap.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0900-097F, U+1CD0-1CF6, U+1CF8-1CF9, U+200C-200D, U+20A8, U+20B9, U+25CC, U+A830-A839, U+A8E0-A8FB;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:italic;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiDyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLmg1hVGdeOYktMqlap.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:italic;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiDyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLmg1hVF9eOYktMqg.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:italic;font-weight:600;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiDyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLmr19VFteOYktMqlap.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0900-097F, U+1CD0-1CF6, U+1CF8-1CF9, U+200C-200D, U+20A8, U+20B9, U+25CC, U+A830-A839, U+A8E0-A8FB;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:italic;font-weight:600;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiDyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLmr19VGdeOYktMqlap.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:italic;font-weight:600;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiDyp8kv8JHgFVrJJLmr19VF9eOYktMqg.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:normal;font-weight:100;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiGyp8kv8JHgFVrLPTucXtAOvWDSHFF.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0900-097F, U+1CD0-1CF6, U+1CF8-1CF9, U+200C-200D, U+20A8, U+20B9, U+25CC, U+A830-A839, U+A8E0-A8FB;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:normal;font-weight:100;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiGyp8kv8JHgFVrLPTufntAOvWDSHFF.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:normal;font-weight:100;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiGyp8kv8JHgFVrLPTucHtAOvWDSA.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:normal;font-weight:200;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLFj_Z11lFd2JQEl8qw.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0900-097F, U+1CD0-1CF6, U+1CF8-1CF9, U+200C-200D, U+20A8, U+20B9, U+25CC, U+A830-A839, U+A8E0-A8FB;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:normal;font-weight:200;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLFj_Z1JlFd2JQEl8qw.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:normal;font-weight:200;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLFj_Z1xlFd2JQEk.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLDz8Z11lFd2JQEl8qw.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0900-097F, U+1CD0-1CF6, U+1CF8-1CF9, U+200C-200D, U+20A8, U+20B9, U+25CC, U+A830-A839, U+A8E0-A8FB;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLDz8Z1JlFd2JQEl8qw.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLDz8Z1xlFd2JQEk.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiEyp8kv8JHgFVrJJbecnFHGPezSQ.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0900-097F, U+1CD0-1CF6, U+1CF8-1CF9, U+200C-200D, U+20A8, U+20B9, U+25CC, U+A830-A839, U+A8E0-A8FB;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiEyp8kv8JHgFVrJJnecnFHGPezSQ.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiEyp8kv8JHgFVrJJfecnFHGPc.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLGT9Z11lFd2JQEl8qw.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0900-097F, U+1CD0-1CF6, U+1CF8-1CF9, U+200C-200D, U+20A8, U+20B9, U+25CC, U+A830-A839, U+A8E0-A8FB;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLGT9Z1JlFd2JQEl8qw.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLGT9Z1xlFd2JQEk.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:normal;font-weight:600;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLEj6Z11lFd2JQEl8qw.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0900-097F, U+1CD0-1CF6, U+1CF8-1CF9, U+200C-200D, U+20A8, U+20B9, U+25CC, U+A830-A839, U+A8E0-A8FB;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:normal;font-weight:600;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLEj6Z1JlFd2JQEl8qw.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:normal;font-weight:600;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLEj6Z1xlFd2JQEk.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:normal;font-weight:700;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLCz7Z11lFd2JQEl8qw.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0900-097F, U+1CD0-1CF6, U+1CF8-1CF9, U+200C-200D, U+20A8, U+20B9, U+25CC, U+A830-A839, U+A8E0-A8FB;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:normal;font-weight:700;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLCz7Z1JlFd2JQEl8qw.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Poppins';font-style:normal;font-weight:700;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiByp8kv8JHgFVrLCz7Z1xlFd2JQEk.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}</style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;font-family:Poppins,sans-serif}</style><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.53fb677d8b432b70b604.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'"><noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.53fb677d8b432b70b604.css"></noscript></head>

<body>
    <app-root></app-root>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ce4ce84306.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
    </script>
<script src="runtime.9a4430f7366c332babeb.js" defer></script><script src="polyfills.e11715d3ca9a8c11dd36.js" defer></script><script src="main.08671498e1fe3c2f409d.js" defer></script>

</body></html>
```

Command that i'm using on windows 10 to compile angular app

```
ng build --configuration="development"
```

✔ Browser application bundle generation complete. ✔ Copying assets complete. ✔ Index html generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files | Names         |      Size vendor.js           | vendor        |   2.90 MB main.js             | main          | 391.71 kB polyfills.js        | polyfills     | 128.54 kB styles.css          | styles        |   7.63 kB runtime.js          | runtime       |
6.27 kB

```
                | Initial Total |   3.42 MB
```

Build at: 2021-10-30T05:47:38.064Z - Hash: c105908e0743f06aebea - Time: 13981ms

Any solution to resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: Also you can try by change in `index.html` file. add `dot` notation before `/`. like this..
`<base href="./">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the port to the URL (don't need to specify index.html), and also try without `angapp`

```
http://localhost:4200/
```

If you're going to test or deploy it with the `/angapp` path segment, you'll need to set the `baseHref` when building or serving the app

```
ng build --base-href="/angapp/"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it resolved the issue but there are images also which are not found `<img src="../assets/logo.png" alt="" />` i have defined it like this inside my component